# How to called special functions in the cmath library in C++?

Tags: c++, identifier, cmath

I am trying to define a function that requires me to make use of something called an "Associated Laguerre Polynomial". It's listed [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/special_functions/assoc_laguerre) under the  library. In visual studio code, intellisense predicts "assoc_laguerre()" as a function so it clearly exists!

Yet, when building the code, it highlights the assoc_laguerre() function with the message: "Identifier not found".

Any help would be very appreciated!
Thanks!

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include<vector>
#include<fstream>
#include<iomanip>
#include<string>
#include<algorithm>
#include<time.h>
#define __STDCPP_WANT_MATH_SPEC_FUNCS__ 1
#include<math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

//Function Definitons:
double a = 5.29177210903*pow(10,-11);
// Normalised Radial Component:
double Radial(double r,int n,int l,int Z){
    double rho, prefactor,R,L,M;
    rho = 2*r*Z/(n*a);
    R=pow(pow(rho/r,3)*tgamma(n-l)/(2*n*tgamma(n+l+1)),0.5)*exp(-rho/2)*pow(rho,l);
    L=R*assoc_laguerre(n-l-1,2*l+1,rho);

    M=L*R;
    return M;



}
int main()
{
    vector<string> msg {"End Process."};

    for (const string& word : msg)
    {
        cout << word << " ";
    }
  
}
```

Comment: assoc_laguerre was [added in C++17](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/special_functions/assoc_laguerre), so make sure you're targeting at least that.

Comment: Hi Putnam, thanks for replying so soon! I'm quite new to C++ programming, so can I ask what you mean by targeting? Thanks

Comment: Have you read the notes in your provided link? You may want to check whether your compiler does or does not implement the noted proposals and if the macro is defined for it.

Comment: @FelixHunter what Putnam is saying is to be sure you are compiling with the support for c++17 enabled. You also need to be sure your compiler is recent enough to support c++17 extensions. You can find many articles on c++17 and on how to compile for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not compiling with the C++ 2017 version of the language standard enabled. Enable it, and this should be available. Your code compiles with GCC 10.1 and `-std=c++17`; but not if we use `-std=c++14` instead.

[<kbd>GodBolt</kbd>](https://godbolt.org/z/HiPZZf)